# Why do I get warning C4844 when compiling a module implementation unit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am trying to split parts of my module implementation into a separate source file as a module implementation unit:

banana.cppm

```c++
export module banana;

export int banana();
```

banana.impl.cppm

```c++
module banana;

int banana() {
    return 42;
}
```

Visual Studio complains about this code with warning C4844:

> 1> banana.impl.cppm(1,14): warning C4844: 'export module banana;' is
> now the preferred syntax for declaring a module interface

What is going on here? How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: There is no `module banana;` syntax see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Syntax

Comment: @RichardCritten There is, look at the second line in the example for the *Module declarations* section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ thinks your module implementation unit is a module interface unit.

There is two possible ways how this could happen:

- You use the [`/interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/interface?view=msvc-170) compile option for compiling the module implementation source file. Right-click the source file and go to `Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As` and make sure that this is *not* set to `Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface)`. If you are using CMake to generate your Visual Studio solutions, remove the module implementation sources from the `CXX_MODULES` `FILE_SET`.
- You are using a module file extension like `.ixx` or `.cppm` for the module implementation source file. Visual Studio automatically treats those as module interfaces. Either override this using the [`/TP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=msvc-170) compile option (set the `Compile As` property from above to `Compile As C++ Code (/TP)`) or change the file extension to a non-module file extension like `.cpp`. I strongly recommend changing the file extension as other compilers similarly assign special meaning to the module file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two ways to get your example to work:

1. As described by ComicSansMS (who gives talks on this sort of stuff, so greater authority than I am).
2. Use the [/internalPartition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/internal-partition?view=msvc-170) option for the relevant files - set the same way as the "Compile as C++" option. This, at minimum, is more explicity about what you are actually intending for the file. I will report further if I find other benefits.